# Customizing Log4j to filter PatternLayout

Tags: log4j, customization, pattern-layout

I have just starting migrating to WLS 10.x and have noticed that the thread name [`%t`] for WL is quite verbose and more informative than I need for my deployment needs.

Ultimately, I only care about the thread ID but WL gives me this:<

```
[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '0' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'
~
```

Does anybody know if there is a way in log4j to write a custom filter that will allow me to override `PatternLayout` so I can parse the WLS Thread Name to just output the thread ID which in this case above is 0 ? I'd rather extend then customize as it makes upgrading libraries so much easier.

Answer (score 0):

You want to write your own conversion word. In logback you can do so within minutes. See the section on [custom conversion specifiers](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/layouts.html#customConversionSpecifier).

If you are really lazy and could not be bothered with writing a custom conversion word, just tell the the existing throwable to trim the thread name to 26 characters. The pattern would be "%.-26thread". I chose 26 because that is the length of "[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '0'".